# java & SWT - how to use masking on images

Tags: image, swt, transparent, masking

i'm trying to use masking on an image in order to set a part of the image to be transparent.

from what i've read , it's supported by the SWT library , but i can't find a way to do it . i can't find even an example for that .

i've therefore created my own way to do it , by implementing the masking part : 
first i find an RGB value that isn't taken anywhere on the image , and then i set it to be the transparency color. then i take the masking image , and use it to put the correct pixel (either transparent or taken from the source image) in order to create a new image.

it works , but i wish i had a simpler method . 
can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This constructor on the Image class looks to do the job:

```
public Image(Device device,
             ImageData source,
             ImageData mask)
```

from the javadoc...

*Constructs an instance of this class, whose type is SWT.ICON, from the two given ImageData objects. The two images must be the same size. Pixel transparency in either image will be ignored.
The mask image should contain white wherever the icon is to be visible, and black wherever the icon is to be transparent. In addition, the source image should contain black wherever the icon is to be transparent.
Parameters:
device - the device on which to create the icon
source - the color data for the icon
mask - the mask data for the icon*

Comment: yes, i saw it too . that's why i asked about it , since i know it should be possible to use something out of the box . have you tried it out? i have,  and i couldn't find out what was missing .